# How do I write this function as declaration?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I write this function with function declaration

```
function sortAge
```

and not expression
like

```
let sortAge = students.sort((a,b) =>a.age - b.age);
```

Comment: You are missing the params: `let sortAge = (students) => students.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);`

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking exactly. You want to make a function and sort the array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a students argument for the sortAge
array function

```
const sortAge = students => students.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the expression inside the function definition.

```
function sortAge(students) {
    return students.sort((a,b) =>a.age - b.age);
}
```